# How to run .NET Tesseract 5.2 in Microsoft ASP.NET Core 6 Linux Docker container?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, tesseract

My goal is to run [.NET Tesseract 5.2](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) in Microsoft ASP.NET Core 6 Docker container: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0`.

But I get an error when trying to initialize the Tesseract engine:

> Failed to find library "libleptonica-1.82.0.so" for platform x64

There are many threads in GitHub ([Ex.1](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/issues/503), [Ex.2](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/issues/529)) or [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813484/error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-tesseract-on-ubuntu-using-net-core-3-1) but there are some issues with them:

1. The questions (and answers) are about Tesseract 4.x
2. Some additional time-consuming steps to take: compile leptonica and tesseract. Install dependencies.
3. `apt-get install libleptonica-dev libtesseract-dev` leads to installing old versions of these libs in `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0`
4. Even if I compile or deploy `.so` files, the other error happens `liblibdl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

**The question**: is there a more simple way to run Tesseract 5 in a Microsoft ASP.NET Core 6 Linux Docker container?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution with some tradeoffs. The significant part of the docker file is the next:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-bookworm-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
        libleptonica-dev \
        libtesseract-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so
WORKDIR /app/x64
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblept.so.5 /app/x64/libleptonica-1.82.0.so
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so.5 /app/x64/libtesseract50.so
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

# Other lines are not important and can be the same as those generated by Visual Studio.
...
```

**Key moments**:

1. The base image is `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-bookworm-slim` - it contains a more recent version of Debian than the default `aspnet:6.0` image. If this is the issue for you, then the only way is to compile `leptonica` and `tesseract` for your Linux version.
2. The soft link `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so` workarounds the problem when Tesseract.NET tries to import `libdl` library and can't find it. This is possible because Tesseract.NET uses only 4 functions from `libdl` that also exist in `libdl.so.2`.
3. During the compilation the whole `/app` folder in the container is replaced with the fresh compiled one. As a consequence, two soft links created for `/app/x64/libleptonica-1.82.0.so` and `/app/x64/libtesseract50.so` will be deleted. It's better to put these two `ln -s ...` lines close to the end of your Dockerfile. But this will not work when run in Debug mode. Due to Visual Studio speed optimization, only the first part of the Dockerfile is executed in Debug. As a workaround, after the first run (you should get the exception), run these two `ln -s ...` lines in the container manually. It will create two `LNK` files in `[YourProject]/x64` folder. These 2 link files will then be copied after each run.
4. As an option, instead of `apt-get install -y libleptonica-dev libtesseract-dev`, you can use `apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr` and have also a command line tool inside the container. It will increase the image size approximately by 20Mb.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in Alpine

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libleptonica.so.6.0.0 /app/ProjectName/x64/libleptonica-1.82.0.so
ln -s /usr/lib/libtesseract.so.5.0.3 /app/ProjectName/x64/libtesseract50.so
ln -s /app/ProjectName/tessdata/eng.traineddata /usr/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
```

Comment: If you intend to show shell commands or similar, use the formatting option to improve readability.