# Use Tesseract in .Net 7 Linux Docker Container? Failed to find library "libleptonica-1.82.0.so" for platform x64

Tags: .net, linux, docker, tesseract

I want to run .NET Tesseract 5.2 .NET 7 Application in a Docker Container, however i do get the error

> System.DllNotFoundException: Failed to find library "libleptonica-1.82.0.so" for platform x64.

I already tried some approaches but none worked for me. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

# Install libs for Tesseract
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt install -y libprotobuf-dev 
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libc6-dev libgdiplus libx11-dev libleptonica-dev software-properties-common wget gnupg2 libleptonica-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated libleptonica-dev 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated libtesseract-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ghostscript --allow-unauthenticated

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["OcrWorkerService/OcrWorkerService.csproj", "OcrWorkerService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "OcrWorkerService/OcrWorkerService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/OcrWorkerService"
RUN dotnet build "OcrWorkerService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "OcrWorkerService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OcrWorkerService.dll"]`
```

Anyone got any idea how i can get it to work?

I also tried another approach I found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71066165/13118130

but the git clone gives me the error

`Error  DT1001  failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cmake .." did not complete successfully: exit code: 1`

`Target "leptonica" requires the language dialect "C17" (with compiler extensions), but CMake does not know the compile flags to use to enable it.`

I didn't know what to do after

Comment: Is you project building a x64 dll (or 32)?  Try downloading at http://www.leptonica.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I continued trying some stuff but nothing worked. So finally, instead of using the Tesseract Nuget package, I resorted to using IronOcr (IronOcr.Linux nuget package), which uses Tesseract and it worked without any issues.My goal was to perform OCR on pdf files, which now works.